# Performance of counting sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

AFAIK [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is using following algorithm:

```
// A: input array
// B: output array
// C: counting array
sort(A,B,n,k)
1. for(i:k) C[i]=0;
2. for(i:n) ++C[A[i]];
3. for(i:k) C[i]+=C[i-1];
4. for(i:n-1..0) { B[C[A[i]]-1]=A[i]; --C[A[i]]; }
```

What about I remove step 3 and 4, and do following?

```
3. t=0; for(i:k) while(C[A[i]]) { --A[i]; B[t++]=i; }
```

Full code [here](http://ideone.com/sXFYHN), looks like fine, but I don't know which one has better performance.

Questions:

1. I guess the complexity of these two versions would be the same, is that ture?
2. In step 3 and step 4 the first version need to iterate n+k times, the second one only need to iterate n times. So does the second one have better performance?

Comment: Your pseudo-code is not the same as the actual code.

Comment: This looks almost like the first variant described in the wikipedia article, but not quite. Are you sure this is correct? It seems weird to index A by i, and even weirder to decrement the elements of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct and it will work in case of sorting numbers. But, suppose you had an array of structures that you were sorting according to their keys. Your method will not work in that case because it simply counts the frequency of a number and while it remains positive assigns it to increasing indices in the output array. The classical method however will work for arrays of structures and objects etc. because it calculates the position that each element should go to and then copies data from the initial array to the output array.

To answer your question:

1> Yes, the runtime complexity of your code will be the same because for an array of size `n` and range `0...k`, your inner and outer loop run proportional to `f(0)+f(1)+...+f(k)`, where f denotes frequency of a number. Therefore runtime is O(n).

2> In terms of asymptotic complexity, both the methods have same performance. Due to an extra loop, the constants may be higher. But, that also makes the classical method a stable sort and have the benefits that I pointed out earlier.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question. It might raise and issue, but it is not an answer.

Comment: @UmNyobe OK then, I will edit and address the specific questions too.